# Shortest way to access json key

Tags: json

I have this kind of json data. And language am using his jquery

```
{
   "Vitals":[
     {
     "Bp Systolic":"",
     "Bp Diastolic":"",
     "Weight":"",
     "Height":"",
     "BMI":""
     } 
   ],
   "Lab":[
    {
    "Lipid_profile":[{
      "Total Cholestrol":"",
      "TRIGLYCERIDES":""
      }],
    "blood":[{
      "A1C":[{ "sample" }],
      "ALBUMIN":"",
      "CALCIUM":"",
      "Glucose":"",
      "POTTASIUM":""
    }]
    }]
   }
```

I want to access the A1C. What will be the efficient way of doing this. I know we can access it by iterating through the json. I am just looking for the efficient way.

**Update:**

as you guys said i have tried this, But am getting it as undefined

```
$.get('sample.json',function(data){
        alert(data.toSource()); //all data
        alert(data.Lab.blood);  //undefined
        });
```

Comment: If you know exactly where you want to go, you can just access it directly: obj.blood.A1C (in whichever language you're using to manipulate the object)

Comment: Lets keep it i know upto blood and unaware of inside things what it got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and cleanest way would be to convert the json-string to an object and then access it with jsonObj.Lab.blood.A1C in any language I would say.

Otherwise you could use regEx to find it or substing to get it but both of these solutions would be ugly if you ask me.

Comment: You mean parse the json into object??

Comment: Yes. This can be done in numerous ways depending on the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the response into a JSON object and access the path 'obj.blood.A1C' as Erik and Sasse said, or you can search for the specific string with a regExp like

```
\"A1C\":\[\{ \"([^\"]*)\"
```

That will return you the contents of the token A1C value into the first matching result group.

If you tell us the programing language maybe we will be able to be a bit more specific.