# how can find json key name or data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Example 1 json response

```
car : [ {
A= [ {name:hero}{name : hero2}]
B= [ {name:hero}{name : hero2}]
}]
```

or Example 2 json response:

```
bus: [ {
    A= [ {name:hero}{name : hero2} ]
}]
```

key name is not fix name.
how can find key name and store key name to string and store json data in array

Comment: try  : NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys]; dict = nsdictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortest way to access json key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095425/shortest-way-to-access-json-key)

Comment: but when multipul data in array .when i don't know what is name is sub array dictionary-----------  Bhadresh

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find all the keys.

```
Use @property(readonly, copy) NSArray < KeyType > *allKeys
```

for accessing all the keys

like you have a JSON response object named jsonObject.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in [jsonObject allKeys]) 
{
  id *object = [jsonObject objectForKey:key];
   [array addObject: object];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
NSArray *carArr ;  ///car array is array which shown in question

NSArray *A = [carArr objectAtIndex:0];  // 0 indicates first object

NSDictionary *dic = [A objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *name = [dic valueForKey:@"name"]; // this will return hero

NSDictionary *dic2 = [A objectAtIndex:1];

NSString *name2 = [dic2 valueForKey:@"name"]; // this will return hero2

// like wise you can do for B and more arrays
```

You can do same bus!

You can go loop through to fetch every name from json object. This is only demonstration that how yo reach to end point in json.